# REGEX: I have file name with extension and date in a string. How to extract only file name with extension not the date

Tags: c#, ssis

I have 3 records with file names with and without dates as shown in the following pic

[image]

I need to **extract only **file name and extension, not the date****. I have used the below code with the help of REGEX

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string a = Row.fullfilename;
        Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"\D+\S\D+");
        if (match.Success)
            Row.filename = match.Groups[0].Value;
        else
            Row.filename = " ";
                       
      
    }
```

I got output as the following pic
[image]

In the first output record, I didn't get an extension and in other records, I got underscores at the first and last of a string

Tons of Thanks for any help!

Comment: Define "date" please

Comment: For `20220602_DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx` what should be the output: `_DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx` or `DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx`?  You've tagged C#, python and ssis, what language/platform do you want the solution in?

Comment: Hi @billinkc first of all thank you for responding. I need output as DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx Actually i am writing code in script component so C# language is preferable

Comment: Today i applied code `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(a, @"\d{8}", " ");` I got output: _DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx but i need output as ***`DEF_ENTERPRISE.xlsx`***

Comment: In the same way for 1st record i got output as ABC1ENTERPRISE_.xlsx but i need output as ***ABC1ENTERPRISE.xlsx*** Thank You

Comment: It sounds like the business rules you need to implement are: Remove 8 consecutive digits from the string and then if the resultant string starts with an underscore or ends with underscore dot xls or xlsx, trim out the underscore.

Comment: If that's an accurate problem statement, the way StackOverflow works is you click Edit to help others understand exactly the problem you're attempting to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to remove the digits and keep all the other characters and extension, this will do the trick:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string a = Row.fullfilename;
        string output = " ";
        Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"[^\d{8}]+"); //removes only sets of 8 digits in a row
        //Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"([^\d]+)"); //removes all digits
        while (match.Success)
        {
            output += match.Groups[0].Value;
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        Row.filename = output;
    }
```

EDIT: Added option to remove specifically 8 digits in a row

Comment: Haven't tested your solution yet, but I would think you'd only want to strip out digits if there's 8 in a row so {8} or whatever the syntax is that I'm not going to look up

Comment: @billinkc I was wondering about that as well.  I'll edit to offer both solutions.  Thanks :)